# Maintaining default value for fields in ArcGIS online map / feature service

Tags: arcgis-desktop, web-mapping, arcgis-online, default-value

I have an enterprise geodatabase within which there are several feature classes that contain subtypes and domains.  A web map has been created from this geodatabase on ArcGIS Online and it is used for data input by many other users.

Within the enterprise GDB, I set the default value for one of the fields in my feature classes and for all subtypes within the feature class.  The web map was then updated with changes.  When I add features directly into the enterprise GDB, the default value is honored within this field.  However, whenever I try to add new features to the web map at ArcGIS Online or on my Collector App, the default value does not populate the field for which it is set.

Do ArcGIS Online maps honor default values for fields?  If so, is there something that I need to be doing to get the default value to automatically fill the field?

Comment: My guess (I could be wrong) is that the [feature templates](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/author-feature-services.htm) for a ArcGIS Server feature service would hold the same truth as the hosted feature service. In short, if the feature template is set with a default value, you'll get that

Comment: Do you see the default values set in the feature service templates at the REST endpoint?

Comment: I think this must be the issue.  I was not aware that I had to create feature service templates that included default values, so following both of your suggestions, I did some reading and checked the REST endpoint.  After, I created new feature service templates with the default value included.  I will update once the feature service is updated at the end of the week.

Answer (score 0):

This thread seems to address this issue- https://community.esri.com/thread/179800